# Does requestAnimationFrame bring advantages when adding/removing DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I have a function which goes through the direct child elements of a DOM node, and appends them to another freshly created Node, when they match a requirement. Then the function replaces the original DOM node with the one I created.

As appending the children to the new DOM node also removes them from the original DOM node, I wonder if I trigger a reflow on each removal, and if it will bring advantages if I wrap the function into `requestAnimationFrame()`. Will this then trigger a reflow only once?

I ask this because [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) only talk about animations and not about adding/removing DOM nodes.

For reference, this is the function:

```javascript
function fix_paragraphs(old){
    cleanup_whitespace(old) // library function

    let fixed = create('div') // library function
    copy_attribs(old, fixed) // library function
    let brs = []
    let p = create('p')

    while (old.hasChildNodes()) {
        const child = old.firstChild
        const childtype = child.nodeType

        if (childtype === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && child.tagName === 'BR') {
            brs.push(child)
            old.removeChild(child)
        }

        else if (childtype === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && child.tagName === 'DIV') {
            if (p.hasChildNodes()) {
                fixed.appendChild(p)
            }
            p = create('p')
            fixed.appendChild(child)
            brs = []
        }

        else if ( (brs.length > 1) && (p.hasChildNodes()) ) {
            fixed.appendChild(p)
            p = create('p')
            p.appendChild(child)
            brs = []
        }

        else if (brs.length === 1) {
            p.appendChild(brs[0])
            p.appendChild(child)
            brs = []
        }

        else {
            p.appendChild(child)
            brs = []
        }
    }

    if (p.hasChildNodes()) {
        fixed.appendChild(p)
    }

    replace_with(old, fixed) // library function
}
```

Comment: If you're worried about speed, you should probably check the performance tab in dev tools and look for "recalculate styles" or "paint" tasks :)

Comment: No removing or adding a DOM node doesn't trigger a reflow, it'll cause one at the next repaint, but if you don't ask a calculated value e.g the offsetWidth of an element, or its innerText, then it won't "trigger" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the function in Dev Tools and figured out, by inspecting the *rasterize paint* entries, how to make it run twice as fast, by first popping the parent element from which I remove nodes (`old` in the code). The updated code goes like this:

```javascript
function fix_paragraphs(old){
    let parent = old.parentNode
    let next = old.nextSibling

    old.remove() // pop it first
    cleanup_whitespace(old)

    let fixed = create('div')
    copy_attribs(old, fixed)

    let brs = []
    let p = create('p')

    while (old.hasChildNodes()) {
        const child = old.firstChild
        const childtype = child.nodeType

        if (childtype === ELEM && child.tagName === 'BR') {
            brs.push(child)
            old.removeChild(child)
        }

        else if (childtype === ELEM && child.tagName === 'DIV') {
            if (p.hasChildNodes()) {
                fixed.appendChild(p)
            }
            fixed.appendChild(child)
            p = create('p')
            brs = []
        }

        else if ( (brs.length > 1) && (p.hasChildNodes()) ) {
            fixed.appendChild(p)
            p = create('p')
            p.appendChild(child)
            brs = []
        }

        else if (brs.length === 1) {
            p.appendChild(brs[0])
            p.appendChild(child)
            brs = []
        }

        else {
            p.appendChild(child)
            brs = []
        }
    }

    if (p.hasChildNodes()) {
        fixed.appendChild(p)
    }

    parent.insertBefore(fixed, next) // now insert it again
}
```

Thanks for the tips, dantechguy and Kaiido.